# What is this mechanism that hides warnings in PHP?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm debugging the PHP code of a big CMS, and I came across the fact that the following code

```
echo _NONEXISTING_CONSTANT_;
```

does not trigger any warning although the constant does not exist. Here is what I've tried to figure out why the warning is not displayed:

- I've checked that `error_reporting() & E_WARNING` returns a non-zero value.
- `ob_get_level()` returns 1.
- If I put the same statement in the beginning of the first `index.php`, the error is displayed, so it's not a config setting.

What are possible mechanisms in PHP in which this code would not trigger a warning?

Comment: How is this related to xampp?

Comment: An [error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) perhaps?

Comment: Or, on php < 8, they could have disabled [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086589/how-to-overcome-php-notice-use-of-undefined-constant)

Comment: I would also ask how you've determined that that constant doesn't exist. Did you `grep` for it or put an actual `defined` check? For the former, many CMSs allow plugins, extensions, drop-ins, etc. to define certain constants.

Comment: Using `error_reporting()` without any parameters will return the current level. What does it return?

Comment: `display_errors` is of course also relevant, if you are expecting errors to appear in the output, and not just a log file.

Comment: I looked but there is no error handler anywhere in the code (no explicit call to set_error_handler)

Comment: The constant does not exist because I wrote die(defined("_NONEXISTING_CONSTANT_") ? "Yes" : "no"); restarted the CMS and got a blank page with "no" on it.

Comment: error_reporting() returns E_ALL, meaning `error_reporting() & E_WARNING` returns a nonzero value, same as `error_reporting() & E_NOTICE`.

Comment: `display_errors` was the answer. It turns out it was set to "1" at the beginning and then "off" at the point the constant was evaluated. @CBroe can you create an answer, I'll accept it.